# JMS uri questions

Tags: c++, jms, uri, activemq-classic

I'm new to JMS. I'm using ActiveMQ CPP (C++ version), but most probably my questions are language agnostic:

1. I saw that using didn't worked

   ```
    failover:(tcp://N.N.N.N)?timeout=1000
   ```

   while this works

   ```
    failover://(tcp://N.N.N.N)?timeout=1000
   ```

   When this change occurred and why?
2. According to [TCP configuration](http://activemq.apache.org/tcp-transport-reference.html), there's option *connectionTimeout*, but I don't see in a code. Do I miss something?
3. Connection  options (e.g. *connnection.closeTimeout*) in case uri looks like *failover:://(tc://N.N.N.N?a=b)?x=y* should be applied to *tcp* or *failover*. Is there good link describing these options in depths?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the ActiveMQ-CPP URI configuration reference here:
http://activemq.apache.org/cms/configuring.html

There are some differences in the URI parsing between the C++, Java and .NET clients due to the available SDKs of each language.

Tim
www.fusesource.com